# (Done) This isn't a duplicate. Needs one more reopen vote

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Colleague is not competent but gets away with it](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/122426/colleague-is-not-competent-but-gets-away-with-it)

Totally different scenario when the OP is a contractor.

Comment: I agree. Voted to reopen.

Comment: Agreed. Both questions are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this isn't a duplicate.

The only way you could see this as a duplicate is if:-

**A)** You didn't read it properly.

**B)** You don't know the difference between a 'Contractor' and a 'Staff member'

**C)** You were parrot voting.

or

**D)** All of the above.

EDIT: to clarify from a comment, I'm not frustrated. But if people are going to continually harp on about closures and duplicates being well thought out for the good of everyone and save the whales and stuff, then their actions should suit their words. Please read a question and make an attempt to understand it before VTC or anything else. Marking as a duplicate can be especially dangerous, if the OP or a future surfer was to take advice that is not applicable, they could easily find themselves unemployed.

**In this particular case the employer has just sacked 20 contractors.**

It's not a game, it's real people with families to support and careers and reputations to advance in life with. It's not a software issue you can mess up and have another go at later. Termination or rep ruined is not something people get a second chance at as par for the course.

If it was a once in the moon misjudgment I wouldn't make a peep, but it's not, it's a trend.

If you don't understand a question then please ask for clarification or leave it to others.

I'm serene on whether anyone feels offended by the bluntness of this answer. My English skills are not up to the task of beating around the bush coherently, so I have to stick with blunt.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? It's a discussion, happy to hear any reasoning. Seems unlikely that adults would downvote purely on sour grapes, but that is the impression it gives.

Comment: I didn't downvote, and I share your frustration that people aren't more forthcoming in explaining their motivations for closing questions (here and in general), and I also agree that this question isn't a duplicate (voted to reopen this morning), but I don't think that "if you voted to close you must be stupid" is especially constructive or helpful. So I can totally imagine someone downvoting (and even flagging) this for that reason.

Comment: The only reason I put in an answer at all is because a mod said that's what we're supposed to do with reopen requests. It's in the linked question. Can't really put an answer in without addressing the question.

Comment: same people who close-vote without comment :/

Comment: @RichardU probably... I thought you retired again mate, good to see you back.

Comment: @Kilisi  Semi-retired.  I won't be around much, but I will be around.