# (Done) Req to reopen Can my employer require me to refrain from wearing headphones (disability issue)

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Can my employer require me to refrain from wearing headphones (disability issue)](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/122438/can-my-employer-require-me-to-refrain-from-wearing-headphones-disability-issue)

I edited this heavily, took out the ranty parts and presented what I think is a more clear question.

disability issues pop up frequently, and I think that this deserves a fair shake.

Comment: 1 more vote required

Comment: 'Does my manager have the right' still sounds like it belongs on law.se...

Comment: It's a great question up to the last part, which asks about rights (with no locale, either) rather than asking how to address the problem with management/corporate.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Disabilitty rights from that perspective are easily answerable fairly universally, regardless of location.  Even in areas with the highest standards don't leave it in the hands of the person with a disability to determine what the accommodation is, only that a reasonable accommodation be provided.  There is no way for that person to bring it to management or corporate without the end result being that he's out the door.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been reopened.

Are we still allowed to use (Done) in the titles? [The meta post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5724/what-is-with-the-done-in-titles-here) about that left me confused as to how we should proceed

Comment: just use it I reckon, I took all mine out and it just made it confusing, so I put them all back in

Comment: The (Done) procedure is still "in place". Also, accepting an answer along the (Done) is also ok