# (DONE) Question was closed as "unclear what you're asking" but has an obvious, single-sentence question in bold

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

[Boredom, lack of projects, search for new opportunity](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/126066/boredom-lack-of-projects-search-for-new-opportunity/)

This question is definitely long winded, and rambling, but I don't understand why it was closed as "unclear what you're asking" when there's a sentence in bold near the very end that is a very clear, and very answerable question,

> **How can I communicate all above, when being interviewed by a new company?**

Can anyone elaborate on this closed reason? Or perhaps vote to reopen and/or help edit it for clarity if it's truly close-able as is?

Comment: Clear enough for me. I voted to reopen.

Comment: @dwizum This is now open.  Can you please accept the answer as per Monica's [open request resolution method](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5725/44108)?

Comment: Yes, all set. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not unclear in the slightest - voted to re-open.